# Trying to install a sw xdg-open: gnome-open: not found

Tags: xdg-open, gnome-open

I am trying to install this program and it gives me this error.

[image]

Comment: Your question is little bit unclear. Please [edit] your post and mention what are you trying to install, how and from where you downloaded that, what version of Ubuntu are you using, etc.

Comment: I am getting the same problem. Have you find a solution so far?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem correctly - the application needs `gnome-open` executable.

It is available from `libgnome2-bin` package (see results from [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=gnome-open)), so you need to install it with

```
sudo apt install libgnome2-bin
```

And `xdg-open` is usually pre-installed as part of `xdg-utils` [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=exactfilename&suite=bionic&section=all&arch=any&keywords=xdg-open&searchon=contents).

Comment: Based on the console message, this is the right answer.
(However, the problem goes much deeper: the "gnome-open" is just used to open Java's website on the browser - to download it, as a form of help.)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is being generated by the OpenJDK. I successful installed this new version of the IRPF software using Oracle Java 11.

I tested this on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. If you are running different version things can potentially be different.

I would recommend you get start by removing the Openjdk. This can be done by issuing the following command:

```
sudo apt-get remove openjdk*
```

Then I suggest you (for the sake of simplicity) to add a PPA to your Ubuntu system in order to easy install Oracle Java 11. My choice was the following one

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java
```

After you added the PPA run

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install oracle-java11-installer
```

It is also recommended to run

```
sudo apt install oracle-java11-set-default
```

In my case nothing happens, but I am mentioning this, just to be sure everything is working. You can now check whether the new Java is correct installed by issuing

```
java -version
```

The desired result is something like this

```
java version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS, mixed mode)
```

If everything is alright I guess you can run the IRPF program. Move to the folder where it was downloaded and then execute it. If you did not change the original file name this would work out as long as you are on the right directory

```
./IRPF2019Linux-x86_64v1.5.bin
```

Now, enjoy doing you IR :)

Comment: Worked like a charm (in 2020)! Thanks!
(Note: current Oracle's Java version is 14.)

Comment: HOWEVER, the "IRPF 2020" program needs Oracle Java 8 to work properly.

By using v. 14, I got the warning "ERRO! O ARQUIVO NÃO FOI TRANSMITIDO. Esta instalação do Receitanet foi corrompida. Reinstale o Receitanet e tente novamente".

In the end, I'd recommend downloading the multiplatform version of "IRPF", that runs smoothly with OpenJDK (by just running "irpf.jar").